# How can i disable specific thread group from command line

Tags: jmeter

I have following Test plan in my jmeter script

```
    TestPlan
    -threadgroup1 
      -script1.jmx
    -threadgroup2
      -script2.jmx
    -threadgroup3
      -script3.jmx
```

So if i pass following values from command line for

```
    threadgroup1 ----threads1 = 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    threadgroup2 ----threads2=0
    threadgroup3--- threads3=5
```

Would it execute only threadgroup1 and threadgroup3 or is there any other way to disable thread group from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I followed the same approach w/o any issues & So I think It should be fine not to execute a thread group as I do not see any option other than updating the jmx file programmatically.